# Can crystal field splitting energy or spin-splitting energy be detected in a density-of-states plot? How?

Tags: density-of-states, transition-metals, spin, crystal-field

What are the signs (if any) in DOS plots that tell us whether we have a big or small crystal-field splitting energy, or spin-splitting energy?  I already asked and got an answer to: [What do we mean by spin-splitting energy?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4737/5)

I am asking in the context of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5022151) which discusses a comparison between spin-splitting energy and [crystal field splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_field_theory) energy, and shows multiple DOS plots.

Comment: Just a comment: the ligand field theory is inherently a multireference theory, so for quantitative estimations of these energies it is advised to go beyond the energy band model and use a multireference method instead, e.g. use the ab initio ligand field theory (AILFT) method in the ORCA software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to reproduce the part of my answer from the [linked question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4737/5) that relates to the spin-splitting.

> I don't believe the spin-splitting or field splitting can be read from the DOS. The way they are mentioned in the paper seems to suggest they are giving a qualitative explanation for seeing all the compounds in high spin configurations. The spectrochemical series gives an ordering of ligands based on how much field splitting they should cause. Since S is known to be a weak-field ligand, it makes sense that the spin splitting energy would be larger than the field splitting, leading to high spin configurations.

As for the crystal-field splitting, perhaps not from the DOS on its own, but the [PDOS](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4867/7) could help you identify the gap in energy between states formed from different types of d-orbitals.